# get same time next year php

Tags: php, datetime

I get this out

```
time: 11:15:04 date: Oct 26, 2015
```

when i click the function calling this code

```
$date = date("Y");
$timestamp = strtotime($date);
$isLeapYear = date("L", $timestamp);
($isLeapYear == 1)? $time_interval = 366 : $time_interval = 365;
$time = time() + $time_interval;
$hours = strftime("%H:%M:%S ",$time);
$date = strftime("%b %d, %Y",$time);
echo 'time: '. $hours;
echo 'date: '. $date;
```

My time in computer is

[image: Time]

1. My question is how can i set the time correctly?
2. Where did the time come from?
3. How can i get the correct time for next year?

Comment: you could use `strtotime("+ 1 year");` (the time is set on your server and not on your computer)

Comment: Time for next year: `
<?php
$date = strtotime(date("Y-m-d", strtotime(("2015-10-26"))) . " +1 year");
echo date("Y-m-d", $date);
?>
`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you just want the exact same time and date plus one year:

you could do:

```
$time = strtotime("+1 year");
```

and display:

```
$hours = strftime("%H:%M:%S ",$time);
$date = strftime("%b %d, %Y",$time);
echo 'time: '. $hours;
echo 'date: '. $date;
```

for this code to work, you have to set the correct time zone and time set on your server.

instead of writing the whole time and date format, you can set the correct locale.

as example

```
setlocale(LC_ALL, 'de_CH', 'de_CH.ISO8859-1', 'de_CH.ISO8859-15', 'de_CH.UTF-8');
echo strftime("%x %X ",$time);
//will output
26.10.2016 11:27:23
```

Comment: One question how will i get the starting date and time of current year. I think i made a mistake in my question. What i really want is to get the starting date of current year

Comment: @Pekka I don't get it. the start date of the year is always 1st of january? or which start date do you want?

Comment: i want that `$time = strtotime("+1 year");` this line will point to Jan 1, 2015 00:00:00 so that when i get the strftime() i get Jan i, 2015 sorry i am currently working on this and i didnt realize that this is what i need not the date today but the start date of year which is jan 1

Comment: if i do `$time = strtotime("+1 year");` , time will be `1477478546` this is date today i want that when i print time it will be the time and date it will be `time:00:00:00 date: Jan 01, 2015` how is this possible

Comment: @Pekka, for next year: `strtotime("01. january + 1 year")`

Answer (score 2):

What about using the [DateTime](http://php.net/manual/en/class.datetime.php) class? It can be really helpful for this kind of operations:

```
$date = new DateTime();
$date->add(new DateInterval("P1Y"));
```

Answer (score 0):

Set `timezone` use `date_default_timezone_set()`:-

```
 //add this line 
    date_default_timezone_set("Asia/Bangkok");//your timezone
    $date = date("Y");
    $timestamp = strtotime($date);
    $isLeapYear = date("L", $timestamp);
    ($isLeapYear == 1)? $time_interval = 366 : $time_interval = 365;
    $time = time() + $time_interval;
    $hours = strftime("%H:%M:%S ",$time);
    $date = strftime("%b %d, %Y",$time);
    echo 'time: '. $hours;
    echo 'date: '. $date;
```

> The date_default_timezone_set() function sets the default timezone
>   used by all date/time functions.